# How to get name of score of synet usinging sentiwordnet

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string and  I want to get a score of pos/neg of each word using a sentiword net. here is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text = "good bad. work hard"
word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
for i in word_tokens:
     synsets=list(swn.senti_synsets(i))
     print(synsets[0])
```

my output has error:

```
<good.n.01: PosScore=0.5 NegScore=0.0>
<bad.n.01: PosScore=0.0 NegScore=0.875>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(synsets[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any idea why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well aparantly the `synsets` is an empty list for `'work'`?

Comment: no, there is a value for work which is 0 (<work.n.01: PosScore=0.0 NegScore=0.0>)

Comment: I think the problem in length of the list, but I don't know why?

Comment: when I print all synsets, it does print all synsets for each word. But I only want the first synset only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare synsets  as list and append all the result to it. This will help:

```
synsets = list()
text = "good bad. work hard"
word_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
for i in word_tokens:
    synsets.append(list(swn.senti_synsets(i)))
    print(synsets[0])
```